# Is there a list of logics?

Tags: logic, big-list, nonclassical-logic

There are a lots of logics. Some of them are:

- Propositional logic
- Predicate logic
- Second order logic
- $n$ order logic
- Fuzzy logic
- Modal logic
- Multivalued logic
- etc

So I`d like to know whether there is a list somewhere in a book or on the internet with it.

Also, are there any efforts to unify or classify all of this mess we created by coming up with such a lot of logics? And what are the kinds of logics that are used in the foundations of Mathematics?

Comment: Classical logic, linear logic, intuitionnistic logic, Hoare logic, combitional logic design !

Comment: For more logics:
Temporal logics ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic#Temporal_logics ), hybrid logics (some kind of contextual logic), quantum logics, legal logics (for computational law), description logics (for AI and programming with better decidability) and basically any combination of constructs in all these logics. They differ by the meaning of the logic value like legal logic or a logic for deciding a text to be part of a (programming) language. Many logics are invented as a language for practical domain-specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

There is [this webpage](http://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Eavrs/ManyValuedLogic/nonstbib.htm) by Peter Suber, but it is 20 years out of date (and I personally find it lacking).  There is also [a helpful Wikipedia category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Non-classical_logic) that lists some more, but is still incomplete (for instance, it's missing hybrid logic and dynamic epistemic logic).

I think the search term to use is "non-standard logics".  And along with ChrisoLosoph's point, I've gotten a lot of mileage from searching "logic and [insert your favorite field here]."

As for the last part of your question, logics are usually classified by their expressivity and complexity.  There is no ["Complexity Zoo"](https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo) for logic (I wish...) -- instead most of these connections are either folklore or in hard-to-find conference papers.  Here are a few pointers:

- One of the first things people want to know about a logic is where it stands in relation to first-order logic. These sorts of results are usually folklore, e.g. modal logics are decidable fragments of first-order logic.
- The relationships between different modal logics are *very* thoroughly studied.  In addition to the classical [Frame Correspondence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#MapRelBetModLog), people have also explored extensions of modal logic that can still be simulated by 'basic' modal logic ([here is a survey](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/mkracht/html/transla.pdf)).
- Evgeny Zolin has put together a very nice [web-navigator](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/%7Eezolin/dl/) for different description logics.
- Hybrid logic has served as a sort of bridge between (afaik) temporal, description, and modal logics (see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2323668_A_Road-Map_on_Complexity_for_Hybrid_Logics)).

I'd love there was a unified wiki for various logics, but for now I hope this helps!

Comment: @311411 Yep, I'll edit that to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such list, and I don't think there is one.

Alternatively, you can take a look at [these](https://plato.stanford.edu/search/search?query=logics) Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy search results and  [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22*+logic%22+site%3Aen.wikipedia.org&oq=%22*+logic%22+site%3Aen.wikipedia.org&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Google search, which is essentially what you're looking for.